# dialog.dismiss() doesn't work on item click inside alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Why dialog.dismiss() doesn't work after click on item inside the AlertDialog ?
I have also tried alert.dismiss but i get the error dialog cannot be resolved. How can i solve that?

Here's the dialog

```
protected void myMarkersDialog() {
     final String name = prefs.getString("Name", "");
     String nameTwoo = prefs.getString("NameTwoo", "");
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_markers_listview, null);
        builder.setView(convertView);
        builder.setTitle("List");
        lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         if (prefs.contains("Name") || prefs.contains("NameTwoo"))
          {

                String[] values = new String[] {name,nameTwoo};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

          }

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg) {
                   String selected;
                   selected = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                   if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                   {
                       mapView.getMapViewPosition().setCenter(myMarkerGeopoint);
                      dialog.dismiss();
                   }

               }
            });

        builder.setNeutralButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss(); // I get error!
           }

        });


        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show(); 
    }
```

Comment: declare the AlertDialog before the builder declaration.
Also, check which dialog object are you accessing. Possibly, you are refering wrong dialog object

Comment: You should likely use cancel instead of dismiss, and you need to cancel your AlertDialog, `alert`, not the interface. As @AtishAgrawal said, you need to declare your alert dialog before your build it or you will get an error.

Comment: so i should use AlertDialog= new AlertDialog(this)?

Comment: no..the above statement will throw error. You need an instance variable name.
just cut the line AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog(this) from your code and paste it above AlertDialog.Builder code.

And use dialog.dismiss

Answer (score 0):

Declare the AlertDialog before build it and use it to dismiss.

```
    AlertDialog alert;

    protected void myMarkersDialog() {
         final String name = prefs.getString("Name", "");
         String nameTwoo = prefs.getString("NameTwoo", "");
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_markers_listview, null);
            builder.setView(convertView);

            ...

            builder.setNeutralButton(getResources().getString(R.string.no_dialog), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alert.dismiss();
               }

            });

            alert = builder.create();

            alert.show();
    }
```